# How do I use the balance classes option for autoML in the flow interface?

Tags: h2o

I'm trying to use autoML in the flow interface for a classification problem.

My response column is a enum data type with values of 1 and 0.

My data set is really imbalanced, around 0.5% of rows have a 1 response.

I want to try the balance classes option, but every time I try it, the program ends up throwing errors.

If I check the balance classes option, am I required to also input values in the class_sampling_factors input box? If so, what do I put in?

The documentation says:

"class_sampling_factors: (DRF, GBM, DL, Naive-Bayes, AutoML) Specify the per-class (in lexicographical order) over/under-sampling ratios. By default, these ratios are automatically computed during training to obtain the class balance. This option is only applicable for classification problems and when balance_classes is enabled."

But it seems like the function fails to run unless I put something in.

I've tried putting in 200.0, 1 and also 1.0,200.0 but neither seemed to work well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to specify the "Class sampling factors" parameter when using "Balance classes".

I just verified on H2O 3.26.0.9 that you can successfully run AutoML with "Balance classes" checked and leaving the "Class sampling factors" blank by using the [HIGGS dataset](https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv) (10k subset).  I also entered 1.0,0.5 for "Class sampling factors" and that worked as well.  I don't see any bugs reported on older versions of H2O (not sure which version you are using), so maybe the error is caused by something else?

Here's the Flow output generated by both options:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm running Version: 3.26.0.8.

Comment: Sorry, hit reply too soon.  
Here's the autoML statement.  
![imgr](https://i.imgur.com/yI5ti3j.png)  
I get this error in the console:  

15532  FJ-2-21   WARN: Grid search: model builder for parameters hex.tree.gbm.GBMModel$GBMParameters@11ee9a55 failed! Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class_sampling_factors must have 2 elementsjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class_sampling_factors must have 2 elements

Comment: I tried your  example after updating to the most recent version, and am still getting the same error.